# How to update a field value to default value in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to mongoDB.

I have defined "photo" field with default value in mongoose schema like this:

```
const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
photo:{
    type:String,
    default: ***an image url***
}
})
```

I have created `/uploadPhoto` route in node.js server which stores photo url given by the user(from frontend) in "photo" field.

I also created `/deletePhoto` route in node.js server which should remove the current photo url and set the default value.

How to do this in `/deletePhoto` function ?

Comment: What do you need to do? a deletePhoto function? try update your question, becouse your doubt is not clear to me yet.